# problem displaying axis values in flex chart

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have a value object something like this

```
public class Data
{

    public var date:Date;
    public var value:int;

            ...

    public function get formattedDate():String
    {
        return date.getDay()+"."date.getMonth()+"."+date.getYear();
    }

}
```

When I use the 'date' field for the category axis everything is fine but when I change that to the 'formattedDate' it doesn't work (the axis has no labels). Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score -1):

Watch types.

When you use `date` you get Number type result.

When you use `formattedDate` you get String type result.

You have to return Number type also using `formattedDate`.

Comment: Actually you don't have to do that. Since it's just a label you can return any type you want (all types in ActionScript have a toString() method)